# getting the white screen while running the code through simulator which is developed by ionic and angular js

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ios,the following is the console log while running the code in xcode simulator.The code is developed by using the ionic framework.I want to provide my app in ios also.so i replaced the www folder with my existing code and tried to run it then i am facing this continuesly.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

objc[7513]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x4ad644c) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x486eb78). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-03-20 20:33:45.152 myProjectName[7513:246533] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/MyCompanyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/036928E0-52A8-4B5C-97EF-C57B1F8A2657/data/Containers/Data/Application/F54A6107-EC48-4068-A629-34E7C43D81DE/Library/Cookies/com.ionicframework.clickadel163468.binarycookies
2017-03-20 20:33:45.378 myProjectName[7513:246533] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.1 is starting.
2017-03-20 20:33:45.379 myProjectName[7513:246533] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-03-20 20:33:45.680 myProjectName[7513:246533] Using UIWebView
2017-03-20 20:33:45.699 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.106990ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.701 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.806021ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.701 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.084996ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.749 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 47.798991ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.768 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 17.942011ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.769 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.886023ms
2017-03-20 20:33:45.769 myProjectName[7513:246533] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 70.329010ms
2017-03-20 20:33:52.930 myProjectName[7513:246533] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-03-20 20:33:54.016 myProjectName[7513:246533] Finished load of: file:///Users/MyCompanyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/036928E0-52A8-4B5C-97EF-C57B1F8A2657/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DF786069-D4D7-4350-A843-5FA0CD094A37/clickadel.app/www/index.html
2017-03-20 20:35:04.438798 myProjectName[7513:246533] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/MyCompanyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/036928E0-52A8-4B5C-97EF-C57B1F8A2657/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-03-20 20:35:04.468354 myProjectName[7513:246533] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

Comment: Can you at least make some editing efforts ?

Answer (score 0):

For angular elements to avoid white screen while loading, add ng-cloak tag in main div and add style like this:

```
[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],.ng-cloak{display:none !important}
```